# Customize Amcharts scrollbar

Tags: angular, amcharts

I am creating a graph for monthly fees using Amchart & Angular 6 and having trouble with the scrollbar section

[image: Here is the result]

Here is my initiation code (some part are truncated)

```
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
const chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.responsive.enabled = true;
// Add data
chart.data = [
  ... data
];
chart.padding(0, 30, 0, 0);
chart.margin(0, 0, 0, 0);
// Create axes
const dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.startLocation = 0;
dateAxis.endLocation = 0;
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.fill = am4core.color("yellow");
dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#ffffff");

// dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.rotation = 90; // rotate the label in case we need it
//
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 50;
// dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;

// Create value axis
const valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
const series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
// let series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.CurvedColumnSeries());
//...
chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();
chart.scrollbarX.height = 5;
chart.scrollbarX.background.fill = am4core.color("#FCFCFC");
chart.scrollbarX.background.fill = am4core.color("#FCFCFC");
chart.scrollbarX.fillOpacity = 1;
chart.scrollbarX.stroke = am4core.color("rgba(0,0,0,.5)");
chart.scrollbarX.strokeWidth = 1;
chart.scrollbarX.margin(30, 30, 30, 30);
chart.scrollbarX.thumb.minWidth = 50;  }
```

I need to customize the scroll bar since it took a lot of space and also be able to customize the left and right arrow.

Answer (score 0):

i have used -     categoryAxis.end = 0.2;

```
categoryAxis.start = 0.8;
```

[check](https://jsfiddle.net/amantandon/evqxr1hd/)